# Photoshop “shadow / object” that replicates “subtraction / differentiation” in all the layers except the background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I would like to know if there is some kind of "shadow / object" that replicates "subtraction / differentiation" in all the layers except the background in photoshop. Adobe illustrator does something similar, but not to the level I'm looking for.

I present an example written with layers:

1. Layer Letters
2. Layer Drawings ("subtraction / differentiation") for all layers except background color
3. Layer shapes
4. ....

I put a visual example.
[image]

I am looking to do this without a "Mask".
Simply by putting a filter on the image (either a border or not) but making the image outline transparent so that the background can be seen, above the other layers.
Imagine you have many images. If I have to make a mask for a lot of images... it might take too long. That's why I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Are you looking for knokouts. Yeah that can be done.

Comment: Any ideas to do this? or PS just can't do it

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works for your specific situation...

However, you could merely add a **Layer Style Stroke** to the top layer, using a color to match any background color.

[image]

You do, of course, get the rounded corners from the stroke. Which I'm aware are not always desired. To get around those round corners...

The only other option I can think of is a mask to hide portions of underlying layers....

[image]

But you do need to create the shape on the mask. It won't be directly tied to any other shape/layer.

Comment: @delive The stroke issues you present is *specifically* why I posted the second option utilizing a **mask**.

Comment: @delive Not sure I understand really... a mask should work.. [as in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH3oh.png)

Comment: Well, ultimately I believe it's a matter of **construction**. I'm working with a *flat jpg* so I don't have constructed artwork with layers and must generate layers. But... well... [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0V8X.gif) -- If you are working with *shape/vector* layers in Photoshop you **can** set the [layer interaction options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eh4V.png) to get a "subtract" function between shape layers.

Comment: "subtract" function between shape layers" It is not a solution.

Comment: Sorry.. I can think of several methods to create such artwork.. but nothing as dynamic as you are seeking. At a *minimum* if text were to change any knockout or mask would also need to be changed, which is simple enough, and **could** be *easily* done via an action, but not dynamically. It may not be possible. Note that I don't think this is *dynamically* possible in Illustrator either. Perhaps someone else will be familiar with a method I am not.

Comment: This does not help the problem. added additional info

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to achieve what you want using *knockout*.

Your bottom layer must be a proper *Background* layer without transparency. So if it's not, use *Layer > New > Background from Layer* to turn it into one.

Place the layer you want to use to subtract above the layers you want to subtract from. It can be any kind of layer or group.

Enter the layer's *Blending Options*. Either double-click the layer (not the name of the layer) or select *Blending Options* from the *Add a layer style* button in the bottom of the *Layers* panel.

Set *Fill Opacity* to *0%* and set *Knockout* to *Shallow* (limits the knockout to the group the layer is in) or *Deep* (makes the layer knockout all layers below it).

[image]

Comment: If you group layers then you can make the knockout only affect the layer gtoup stack.

Comment: @joojaa, yes with *Knockout* set to *Shallow*. I should perhaps make that clearer.